# calculate average score for each array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am struggling to find the right way to calculate the average score for each array in the object.
There are 199 arrays and I need to calculate the average score for each one and return as output

```
const grouped = {}
const score = {}

obj.forEach(function (a) {
  grouped[a.sentence_pair_id] = grouped[a.sentence_pair_id] || []
  score[a.sentence_pair_id] = score[a.sentence_pair_id] || []

  grouped[a.sentence_pair_id].push({ sentence_pair_id: a.sentence_pair_id, score: a.score, evaluator_id: a.evaluator_id })


  score[a.sentence_pair_id].push({ score: a.score })

})

console.log(JSON.stringify(score, 0, 2))
```

This is what I am having so far.
Can someone please give a suggestion on to crack on with this?
In the second exercise, I have to return a JSON that contains the average score plus min and max number
Thanks

```
{
  "BG_SE_1": [
    {
      "score": "45"
    },
    {
      "score": "52"
    },
    {
      "score": "46"
    },
    {
      "score": "49"
    },
    {
      "score": "44"
    }
  ],
  "BG_SE_2": [
    {
      "score": "17"
    },
    {
      "score": "9"
    },
    {
      "score": "13"
    },
    {
      "score": "15"
    },
    {
      "score": "12"
    }
  ],
  "BG_SE_4": [
    {
      "score": "92"
    },
    {
      "score": "94"
    },
    {
      "score": "90"
    },
    {
      "score": "96"
    },
    {
      "score": "94"
    }
  ],
  "BG_SE_5": [
    {
      "score": "11"
    },
    {
      "score": "14"
    },
    {
      "score": "17"
    },
    {
      "score": "15"
    },
    {
      "score": "13"
    }
  ],
  "BG_SE_6": [
    {
      "score": "63"
    },
    {
      "score": "65"
    },
    {
      "score": "64"
    },
    {
      "score": "66"
    },
    {
      "score": "69"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Loop over the properties. In each property, sum the scores and divide by the length of the array to get the average. Put that in a property of the returned object.

Comment: You can't use `obj.forEach()`. You can use `Object.entries(obj).forEach()` or `Object.keys(obj).forEach()`.

Comment: What is `sentence_pair_id`? There are no properties like that in your objects.

Comment: ```const obj = [
{"sentence_pair_id":"BG_SE_1","evaluator_id":"BBC_Bulgarian_01","score":"45","human_translation":"Защо американският флаг се развява?","machine_translation":"Как се развява това американско знаме?","original":"How did that US flag wave?"}
,
{"sentence_pair_id":"BG_SE_1","evaluator_id":"DW_Bulgarian_01","score":"52","human_translation":"Защо американският флаг се развява?","machine_translation":"Как се развява това американско знаме?","original":"How did that US flag wave?"}```
,
This is my original object

Comment: Put that in the question, not a comment.

Comment: sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `obj` as an array of objects:

```
let obj = [ 
  {"sentence_pair_id":"BG_SE_1","evaluator_id":"BBC_Bulgarian_01","score":"45","human_translation":"Защо американският флаг се развява?","machine_translation":"Как се развява това американско знаме?","original":"How did that US flag wave?"},
  {"sentence_pair_id":"BG_SE_1","evaluator_id":"DW_Bulgarian_01","score":"52","human_translation":"Защо американският флаг се развява?","machine_translation":"Как се развява това американско знаме?","original":"How did that US flag wave?"},
] 

let grouped_scores = obj.reduce(function(memo, item) {
  if (!memo[item.sentence_pair_id]) {
    memo[item.sentence_pair_id] = {score: 0, count: 0}
  }

  memo[item.sentence_pair_id].score += Number(item.score)
  memo[item.sentence_pair_id].count += 1
  return memo
}, {})

let grouped_average_scores = Object.keys(grouped_scores).reduce(function(memo, key) {
  memo[key] = grouped_scores[key].score / grouped_scores[key].count
  return memo
}, {})
```

Results in:

`{BG_SE_1: 48.5}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` method on array to calculate the sum and then average. Similarly same logic can be used for min and max. Something like this

```js
const input = {
  "BG_SE_1": [
    {
      "score": "45"
    },
    {
      "score": "52"
    },
    {
      "score": "46"
    },
    {
      "score": "49"
    },
    {
      "score": "44"
    }
  ],
  "BG_SE_2": [
    {
      "score": "17"
    },
    {
      "score": "9"
    },
    {
      "score": "13"
    },
    {
      "score": "15"
    },
    {
      "score": "12"
    }
  ],
  "BG_SE_4": [
    {
      "score": "92"
    },
    {
      "score": "94"
    },
    {
      "score": "90"
    },
    {
      "score": "96"
    },
    {
      "score": "94"
    }
  ],
  "BG_SE_5": [
    {
      "score": "11"
    },
    {
      "score": "14"
    },
    {
      "score": "17"
    },
    {
      "score": "15"
    },
    {
      "score": "13"
    }
  ],
  "BG_SE_6": [
    {
      "score": "63"
    },
    {
      "score": "65"
    },
    {
      "score": "64"
    },
    {
      "score": "66"
    },
    {
      "score": "69"
    }
  ]
};

Object.keys(input).forEach(item => {
  const sum = input[item].map(i => i.score).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => parseInt(accumulator, 10) + parseInt(currentValue, 10));
  const avg = sum / input[item].length;
  console.log(item, avg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here I added one example related to your case. I hope it will help you for finding the min, max and avg score by array items.

```
 var testObj = {
            "BG_SE_1": [
                {
                    "score": "45"
                },
                {
                    "score": "52"
                },
                {
                    "score": "46"
                },
                {
                    "score": "49"
                },
                {
                    "score": "44"
                }
            ],
            "BG_SE_2": [
                {
                    "score": "17"
                },
                {
                    "score": "9"
                },
                {
                    "score": "13"
                },
                {
                    "score": "15"
                },
                {
                    "score": "12"
                }
            ],
            "BG_SE_4": [
                {
                    "score": "92"
                },
                {
                    "score": "94"
                },
                {
                    "score": "90"
                },
                {
                    "score": "96"
                },
                {
                    "score": "94"
                }
            ],
            "BG_SE_5": [
                {
                    "score": "11"
                },
                {
                    "score": "14"
                },
                {
                    "score": "17"
                },
                {
                    "score": "15"
                },
                {
                    "score": "13"
                }
            ],
            "BG_SE_6": [
                {
                    "score": "63"
                },
                {
                    "score": "65"
                },
                {
                    "score": "64"
                },
                {
                    "score": "66"
                },
                {
                    "score": "69"
                }
            ]
        }

        // object with array result of min,max,avg
        var arrObj = [];       

        for (var propt in testObj) {      

            var dataLength = testObj[propt].length;
            var arrData = [];
            var total = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                arrData.push(testObj[propt][i].score);
                total += testObj[propt][i].score;
            }
            Math.max.apply(Math,arrData); 
            Math.min.apply(Math, arrData);

            arrObj.push( {
                name: propt,
                MinScore: Math.min.apply(Math, arrData),
                MaxScore: Math.max.apply(Math,arrData),
                AvgScore: total/dataLength
            });

        }
```